# Windows are too big to see all buttons or toolbar when using low resolution screen

Tags: settings, resolution

I'm using Elementary OS on a mini-laptop where maximum resolution supported is 1024x600. There are some windows, like settings where some buttons are not visible because they are in the lower part of the window. Is there any way to zoom out the screen to see everything even loosing quality? 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I changed font size to minimal in settings.
My display support resolution 1024x720 only.

Update:
Settings -> Desktop -> View (maybe) -> Text size.

Sorry, my system language is russian. I am so lazy for change.
[image: Settings - Desktop]
[image: View - Text Size]

Comment: Hello. Please provide a more detailed answer on how you did that so that begginers can do it more easily.